# Not able to see textbox in asp.net mvc page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am entirely new to asp.net mvc and this is my first sample project that I need to show one textbox in one view when the user entered a value in that textbox, I need to display that value in label in another view.
for that I have done like this ..

this is my controller class

```
public class TextBoxController : Controller
{
  //
  // GET: /TextBox/

   public ActionResult Index()
   {
     return View();
   }
}
```

and this is my model class

```
namespace MvcTestApplication.Models
{
  public class TextboxModel
  {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name= "Textbox1")]
    public string EnteredValue { get; set; }
  } 
}
```

and this is my view

```
@model MvcTestApplication.Models.TextboxModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "TextboxView";
}

<h2>TextboxView</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <div>
   <fieldset>
       <legend>Enter Textbox Value</legend>
       <div class ="editor-label">
       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EnteredValue)
       </div>
       <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.EnteredValue)
       </div>
       <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Value" />
        </p>
     </fieldset>
   </div>
 }
```

I am not able to see any textbox and any button on page and I am getting error like

**HTTP:404 :  Resource Cannot be found**

I am using visual studio 2012 and mvc4..

would any pls suggest any idea on this one ..
Many thanks..

Comment: What URL are you using?

Comment: i am just getting url like this.. localhost:2234

Comment: Try `localhost:2234/TextBox` (or look at your route config)

Comment: Try this url localhost:2234/TextBox/Index

Comment: Try this rename TextBoxController with some other name, because this is reserve word

Comment: I have tried this one http://localhost:2234/TextBox ... I am getting empty page in that i am able to see this word "Index"....not able to see textbox and button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RE-WRITTEN**

In simple terms, to access a page on ASP.NET MVC, you should point the URL to its controller name. In this case, `TextBox`:

```
localhost:2234/TextBox/TextBox
```

Also, you forgot to add an `ActionResult` for this new view. When you're loading the page, it's going through the `Index` one, which is empty.

The final code should look like this:

**Controller**

```
public class TextBoxController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult TextBox(MvcApplication1.Models.TextBoxModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
public class TextBoxModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Textbox1")]
    public string EnteredValue { get; set; }
}
```

**Razor View (Index)**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

**Razor View (TextBox)**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TextBoxModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TextBox";
}

<h2>TextBox</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter Textbox Value</legend>
        <div class ="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EnteredValue)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.EnteredValue)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Value" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
 }
```

Comment: I have tried this one localhost:2234/TextBox ... I am getting empty page in that i am able to see this word "Index"....not able to see textbox and button

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Just seen it.

Comment: What if you try `localhost:2234/TextBox/Index`?

Comment: i am getting same word "Index" on the screen ... even if i typed this one localhost:2234/TextBox/Index

Comment: That's really weird. Let's go through the project structure/files then. Tell me the file names of your `controller`, `model` and `view`. Also, on which folders they are placed.

Comment: Not at all. That's what makes MVC so amazing compared to WebForms. No code needed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34050/discussion-between-pratap-k-and-melanciauk) if you have time

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have registered the URL via route config.

Find more about asp.net routing **[here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=814)**

**UPDATE:**

**Make sure that file name of your view is `Index.cshtml`** since your controller doesn't specify any return view names.

Comment: If there's no different parameters than the usual, you don't need to change the routes.